# How do I use markdownify in Jekyll to show an excerpt on the index

Tags: markdown, jekyll, liquid

I'm looking to show a short excerpt of text from a longer post or page on the index page. I was going to use a custom variable in the Front Matter and grab that, but then I saw the filter for `.excerpt`

I see in the [Jekyll docs](http://jekyllrb.com/docs/templates/) there's something called `{{ page.excerpt | markdownify }}` How would I markup the markdown on a page or post in order to use that filter?

edit: Or does markdownify take the entire .md document?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

In the post markdown files you need to first set your excerpt, here is an example from one of my posts

```
layout: post
title: A developers toolkit
date: Friday 14 December, 2012
excerpt: What text editor to use? Sass or plain old CSS? What on earth is Compass? Command    line? I'm not touching that. Sound like you? Welcome, I was once like you and this is the guide I wish someone had given me.
```

Then on the index page call the tag

```
{{ post.excerpt }}
```

This should then output what you have wrote in the markdown file. Nice and simple and why I love Jekyll.

Answer (score 80):

Jekyll has an option [`excerpt_separator`](http://jekyllrb.com/docs/posts/#post-excerpts), which is suitable for you.
Things go like this:

In `_config.yml`:

```
excerpt_separator: <!--more-->  # you can specify your own separator, of course.
```

In you post:

```
---
layout: post
title: Foo
---

This appears in your `index.html`

This appears, too.

<!--more-->

This doesn't appear. It is separated.
```

Note you must type exactly `<!--more-->`, not `<!--More-->` or `<!-- more -->`.

In your `index.html`:

```
<!-- Loop in you posts -->
{% for post in site.posts %}
  <!-- Here's the header -->
  <header>
    <h2 class="title"><a href="{{ post.url }}">{{ post.title }}</a></h2>
  </header>

  <!-- Your post's summary goes here -->
  <article>{{ post.excerpt }}</article> 
{% endfor %}
```

The output is like this:

```
<header>
  <h2 class="title"><a href="Your post URL">Foo</a></h2>
</header>

<article>

This appears in your `index.html`

This appears, too.

</article>
```

Comment: @kaplan This is the better suited answer. It should be accepted.

Comment: @kleinfreund In fact, I answered the question several months after the first answer was accepted.

Comment: I know that. That's why I commented. It's the better suited answer.

Comment: @MaxfanZone: Is there a way to specify expert separators before and after the required text? For example, I want the post to show the text-only excerpt without pulling out any images/embedded videos?

Answer (score 3):

doesnt work for mu, or collections, jekyll panics when hitting the except parsing liquid. I dont know why this is, it should work as you suggest.

there is an alternative:

post.content or as my case is: blogX.content and smash it through some text filters that limit the content size.

ie:
{{ blog.content | strip_html | truncatewords: 100 }}

Answer (score 1):

As of ref `84cfc1cef` the github version of [jekyll](/questions/tagged/jekyll) supports the per-post  `excerpt_separator` so you have to add the reference to **Gemfile**:

```
gem 'jekyll', github: 'jekyll/jekyll', ref: '84cfc1ceff0474fd3eb3beb193ae59ae43694863'
```

and create a post with the following `YAML`:

```
---
title:  Post Excerpt Separator
excerpt_separator: "\n---\n"
---
```