# How can I get a post excerpt in Jekyll?

Tags: text, web, blogs, jekyll

I'm creating a new blog using [Jekyll](https://jekyllrb.com).

On the main page, there will be a list of my 10 most recent posts.

The entries on this list will include a title, the post date, and an *excerpt*, most likely the first paragraph.

I'm only familiar with using Jekyll for basic templates, so I can either put only a variable in the page, or include the entire post.

Is there a way to somehow avoid using `post.content` in the paginator, and only include up to a certain point in the post, which I define (e.g. ``{% endexcerpt %}`?

Comment: Also see [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/18007879/1005481).

Answer (score 60, accepted):

Sure, you can use `{{ post.excerpt }}` in place of `{{ post.content }}`.

You can also manually override the automatically generated excerpts if you don't like them.

Full documentation on how to do this here: 
http://jekyllrb.com/docs/posts/#post-excerpts

Comment: Remember to use `<!--more-->` in the actual post to tell Jekyll where it should 'cut' the post for the excerpt content or set excerpt_separator globally in your `_config.yml`.

Answer (score 96):

Something like `{{ post.content | strip_html | truncatewords: 50 }}` produces a more consistent excerpt. It gets the first 50 words and strips any formatting.

Comment: Agreed. This is much better. I used to use excerpt and it would give all kinds of quirks about where it breaks (seemingly only on the first paragraph).

Comment: How would you deal with links though? For example, if you have content like this "This is a post. And a [link](www.link.com)", then the snippet you posted would display the entire raw text rather than being intelligent about it and showing link simply as text.

Comment: Got the answer, use {{ post.content | markdownify | strip_html | truncatewords: 50 }}

Comment: How to get post.content but without post.title? I don't want title in post excerpt.

Comment: Hi, I found that this sentence could only be used in English, When I want to write a Chinese article, how can I use this function? Thanks!

Comment: You can use `truncate: 50` for the first 50 characters. I'm not sure how well this works with Chinese or other Utf-8 sequences without an example, though. `post.excerpt` should probably be improved at some point, I'd personally much rather use a plugin to do that, than stringing together a bunch of liquid filters. https://shopify.github.io/liquid/filters/truncate/

Comment: `truncate: 50` truncates the first 50 characters but it is not consistent. For my Chinese posts I usually use this generic method, and provide an override if the formatting doesn't work out well by default.

Answer (score 5):

Use

```
 {{ post.content | markdownify | strip_html | truncatewords: 50 }}
```

instead of `{{ post.excerpt }}` or `{{ post.content }}`.

This will give consistent length blocks of unformatted text with no raw markdown content in them. Tidy.

---

*Thanks to [this comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19389451/how-can-i-get-a-post-excerpt-in-jekyll#comment73082842_23504519) by [@karolis-ramanauskas](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1386665/karolis-ramanauskas) for the answer, I've made it a proper answer so it can get better visibility.*

Answer (score 4):

To get a custom length excerpt for each post, you can add a `excerpt_separator` variable in front matter of your post. If you set this variable to `<!--end_excerpt-->`, then `post.excerpt` will include all content before `<!--end_excerpt-->`.

```
---
excerpt_separator: <!--end_excerpt-->
---

This is included in excerpts.

This is also included in excerpts.

<!--end_excerpt-->

But this is not.
```

To save yourself the effort of adding `excerpt_separator` to front matter of each post, you can simply set it in `_config.yml`.

Answer (score 0):

What worked for me was: add this to the config.yml : `excerpt_separator: "<!--more-->"  #global excerpt separator for the blog posts` and remember to restart the jekyll local server. All changes to config.yml requires a restart to take effect